# Why does this cause a C stack overflow?

Tags: lua, stack-overflow, lua-table, metatable, meta-method

I'm aware that I can fix this problem by using `rawset`, but I'm just wondering why the following code causes a C stack overflow.

```
local mt = {
    __newindex = function(self, key, value) 
        self[key] = value 
    end
}

local x = setmetatable({}, mt)

x.y = 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [Deep Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_deep_recursion).

Inside the call to the metamethod `__newindex`, `self[key] = value` calls the metamethod `__newindex` again, recursively, until stack overflow.